# Angular Material flex="50" only for layout="row"

Tags: css, angularjs, flexbox, angular-material

We are using angular-material to create a new respsonsive website.

For now we only use the flex-layouts from angular-material.
We have code like this:

```
<div layout="column" layout-gt-md="row">
    <div flex="50">
        Here's some text without a fixed length.
    </div>
    <div flex="50">
        Here's some text without a fixed length.
   </div>
</div>
```

In this case we want to achieve, that we have rows (left to right) on large displays with a width of 50% each.
But the problem is: if its  a medium or smaller device, it has 50% height (`max-height` to be more precise) which causes some overlap with the other `div` as the text is longer than the 50% height of the `div`.

How can we achieve, that the `flex="50"` only applies for `layout="row"` and the column height adapts to the content size?
Overriding the CSS class to

```
.layout-column > .flex-50 {
    max-height: inherit;
}
```

doesn't work.

I've provided a [demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/n3r2CBArmzj2cqGeLgeU?p=preview) of the problem on Plunker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was Visual Studio's way of creating HTML files and our oversight.

Adding `<!DOCTYPE html>` fixed the problem....embarrassing.

But thanks to [@srijith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3768253/srijith)'s Plunker I finally noticed it.

Comment: Just noticed your answer! Anyway, check out my updated response as well. Good luck!

Comment: Your solution also looks interesting....  we always had a height of 100% when we set the max-height to 100% somehow. That means it had too much whitespace between the divs.

Comment: Yeah or the 100% was overriden by 33%. My `!important` seems to pick up the 100%

Answer (score 0):

I tried your problem in a plunker and for smaller screens, the height does adapt to the content of the div.

Check this plunker right [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/uuhAEzK8RIfL5si6LQzE?p=preview)

This is what I used as well

```
<div layout="column" layout-gt-xs="row">
 <div flex="50" style="border: 1px solid green;">
  <Really long text here>
 </div>
 <div flex="50" style="border: 1px solid green;">
  Here's some text without a fixed length.
 </div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE**:

> I forked your plunker and fixed it. Basically the `flex-33` class was adding a `max-height` of 33%. I just set the `max-height` to 100%

[Updated plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/Nq5GCoN7cKom9lr9Pxjl?p=preview)

Comment: It does indeed look like expected. My local test results are:  MS IE - overlap;  Chrome 52 - overlap;  MS Edge - looks like expected; FF Dev 49.0a2 - looks like expected.
Does plunker have a different rendering engine? (tested with chrome and it looks fine, but "real" website overlaps when the viewport gets too small, so the text gets longer).

Comment: I see. Do you have a parent div or something that could create this behavior? Better yet, if you could get a plunker demonstrating your problem, that would be awesome

Comment: Here you go Sir:  https://plnkr.co/edit/n3r2CBArmzj2cqGeLgeU?p=preview  it shows the problem when you make the preview-area smaller.

Comment: I have updated the answer. You need to override the `max-height` on the `flex-33` class

Comment: I noticed that the ```<!DOCTYPE html>``` was missing which fixed the problem. Your Plunker demo had it and it worked there. ;-)